# Metrics on upper half-plane and sphere: natural way

Tags: geometry

In the Euclidean plane, the distance between two points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ is defined by considering a Pythagorean triangle in which the line segment joining $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ will become a diagonal; the other two sides of the triangle have length $(x_2-x_1)$ and $(y_2-y_1)$.
[image]

Thus, a natural way to define a metric on Euclidean plane is by Pythagorean triangles.

**Question:** What is a natural way to define metric on upper half pane (hyperbolic geometry) and on sphere (spherical geometry).

I saw the formulae for the distance between two points in these two other geometries, which are in terms of $\log$ or triagonometric functions. I didn't find any natural way to understand how they arise. Can you help me?

Comment: Well, first of all, do you understand hyperbolic geometry and spherical geometry? Can you interpret a function in spherical coordinates, for instance?

Answer (score 0):

The most immediately obvious way to put a metric on a sphere is to inherit the Euclidean metric in $\mathbb R^3$. However, there are lots of ways to (smoothly) embed a sphere in $\mathbb R^3$ (or higher dimensions), not all of them immediately recognizable as a sphere, but each one will give rise to a different inherited metric (for instance, imagine an embedding where the north and south poles are quite close).

Ultimately, these metrics are not satisfactory because they are not *intrinsic* to the geometry of the sphere. They depend on how the sphere is embedded in its ambient space. To emphasize that I'm now thinking about the sphere as a space in its own right, separate from any embedding in Euclidean space, I will denote the sphere by $\mathbb S^2$.

To define an intrinsic metric, one that depends only on the internal geometry of $\mathbb S^2$, we use *geodesic segments*. Thinking about the sphere in the usual way (i.e., embedded in $\mathbb R^3$ in the usual way), geodesic segments are segments of great circles. In general, geodesics play the same role as straight line segments do in Euclidean geometry.

The distance between two points $a,b \in \mathbb S^2$ is then defined to be the infimum of the lengths of all geodesics beginning at $a$ and ending at $b$. In well-behaved spaces, this will give rise to a metric.

---

Now, hyperbolic geometry is a tad... different.

For starters, $\mathbb S^2$ is topologically distinct from $\mathbb R^2$ and the differences in the topologies plays a part in the geometric differences. However, the hyperbolic plane is homeomorphic (topologically identical) to $\mathbb R^2$.

Calling the upper half plane the hyperbolic plane is a bit disingenuous; properly, the upper half plane together with the right choice of things to call straight lines (i.e., geodesics) provides a *model* for hyperbolic geometry. You may or may not have seen other models of hyperbolic geometry such as the Klein and Poincare models.